# AWS PHP SDK GetObject command error

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We use some script on PHP which get object from S3 and process it. I get object from S3 with next code:

```
$command = $this->s3Client->getCommand(
    'GetObject',
    [
        'Bucket'                  => $backetName,
        'Key'                     => $objectKey,
        'ResponseContentEncoding' => 'identity'
    ]
);
return $this->s3Client->execute($command)->toArray();
```

Today I found that this script returns error:

"Error executing \"GetObject\" on \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/backet-name/object-key?response-content-encoding=identity\"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 61: Unrecognized or bad HTTP Content or Transfer-Encoding".
This script has worked fine some months before.

I tried use another ResponseContentEncoding and finally remove this option, but result was same. Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you able to open the bucket item in a web browser?

Comment: yes. Furthermore, in script I check if object exists in S3 with doesObjectExist method. And only if object exists I try to get it.

Comment: What if you use S3Client->getObject instead?

`$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
 'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
 'version' => 'latest'
]);
$s3 = $sdk->createS3();
$result = $s3->getObject([
 'Bucket' => 'www.pantanourbano.com',
 'Key' => 'carters.json'
]);`

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I tried to get object with getObject method and have got same result. I use 3.2.6 version.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the Bucket name correctly being included? In your code it says "$backetName" not "$bucketName"